# Tracking memory process wise on Ubuntu

Tags: server, memory-usage, rails

I have an rails 3 application with 100-200 daily unique visitors. The
total memory consumed on the server(Ubuntu) is around 1.5-2 GB. I want to know
how much memory is used by each process. What are the best tools to
track memory used by different processes?

Answer (score 10):

You could just fire up `top` and press <kbd>M</kbd> to sort processes by memory usage.

You could run `ps vax | sort -k8n` to show processes sorted by the resident stack usage (`ps v` switches to a memory-centric view).

You could enable snmp and configure mrtg to periodically poll the system, generating a graph of how much memory is used by the processes you care about.

You could resign yourself to the knowledge that Ruby, for all its benefits, is terrible at managing memory in long-running processes. :)

You could combine a more complicated *ps* command line (look at the man page, and read about the -o option) and `rrdtool` with a shell script to generate historical statistics on the processes you care about.

Etc.

Comment: `htop` is a nice extension of top using colours to enhance the readability and provide more info. It's interface is otherwise quite similar to `top`

Comment: +1 for letting me know `ps vax`, for better view `ps vax | sort -k8n | tail` can be used.

Answer (score 3):

Memory management is very difficult, but you can use `top`, `htop` or, as dannysauer suggests, something like `ps vax | sort -k8n`. If you want to get an overview/summary, then `free -m` is nice.

But it is common for processes to consume less memory than they use. For instance, if you have ten processes using 10MB each, that does not mean those processes will consume 100MB. The reason for this is that Linux will recognize identical memory portions between processes so you don't need to have many identical copies. In other words, your system can always use more memory than you have. So you really need to separate between memory consumption and memory usage.

It's not always easy.